# Dialog is re-presented after onPause()->removeDialog() - why?

Tags: android, dialog

I'm just not getting why this is happening:

Successfully create dialog and instantiate it when user clicks on an item.  Zero problems getting dialog to show when desired and to go away when back is pressed....

The problem is: 
  If the dialog is still displaying when the application/activity goes away (pause, die), when it returns, the dialog is still presented but no variables which are context specific are presented.  Note:  I do issue removeDialog() for the dialog in the onPause().  Yet mystically when the app returns, it's somehow cycled thru onPrepareDialog() and loaded up with missing variables (xml names show).

What I want is for the dialog to go away and let the user make a different choice from the main activity and then redisplay the dialog - if that's what they want.  Or said another way - I want dialog to always go away if the app goes away.

I've looked into persisting the data but there doesn't seem to be a "right" spot in the restore process to do that (or I'm just ignorant).  I can't figure out why onPrepareDialog is getting invoked during onResume()....